# how to produce glare on an image with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

Is there a way to produce a glare on an image? Given an image with an object, I want to produce a glare on a portion of an image. If I have an image that is 256x256, I want to produce glare on the first 64x64 patch. Is there a function in opencv I can use for that? If not, what is a good way to go about this problem?

Comment: Can you attach sample input and expected output as well ?

Comment: see this http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted

Comment: Hiii Money did you get any different solution other than the answer

Comment: @coder_v_3.0 Nope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this example does what you need. Each time it saves a face, it gives a flash in the part of the screen where the face was recognised. So, the glares changes every time of place and size.

You can found it here:
https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition

Seek this part in the main.cpp:

```
                // Make a white flash on the face, so the user knows a photo has been taken.
                Mat displayedFaceRegion = displayedFrame(faceRect);
                displayedFaceRegion += CV_RGB(90,90,90);
```

Comment: this seems to work. I compared it with changing the contrast and it seems like changing the contrast shows slightly more realistic glare. But this is definitely another way of doing it!